# drawing and editing on simple image using leaflet.draw lib

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet.draw lib. and trying to built drawing toolbar on the simple image, it displaying fine but its action doesn't works.

```
<div id='image-map'></div>
```

and my script is

```
<script>
url = 'images/leafletTest.png';
var bounds = [[-26.5,-25], [1021.5,1023]];
var image = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);
 map = new L.Map('image-map', {layers: [image], crs: L.CRS.Simple, minZoom : -5});
map.fitBounds(bounds);


    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

// Set the title to show on the polygon button
L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw a sexy polygon!';

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polyline: false,
        polygon: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: true
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        remove: true
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
    if (type === 'marker') {
        layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

map.on(L.Draw.Event.EDITED, function (e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    var countOfEditedLayers = 0;
    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        countOfEditedLayers++;
    });
    console.log("Edited " + countOfEditedLayers + " layers");
});
</script>
```

[image]

when ever i draw a rectangle or marker it doesn't display.

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/weq/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Ooh! it was my fault, i was working with more than two map and script.It was just code conflict !